# Errors occur when compiling caffe files in its installation (Makefile.config)

Tags: machine-learning, compilation, computer-vision, installation

**Could someone *help me* with these errors while compiling *caffe* during installation?**

**this is the Makefile.config of caffe files modified by me**

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
# OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := ATLAS
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        # /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME) /home/desmond/anaconda2
PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME) /home/desmond/anaconda2/include \
        $(ANACONDA_HOME) /home/desmond/anaconda2/include/python2.7 \
        $(ANACONDA_HOME) /home/desmond/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
# PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
#                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
#PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
PYTHON_LIB := $/home/desmond/anaconda2/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

**And then the corresponding compiling result(or errors)**
**(Tip: 错误 means error or wrong)**

```
desmond@desmond-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y400:~/caffe-master$ make all -j4
CXX src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.cpp
CXX src/caffe/parallel.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:40:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/db.hpp:6,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/db_leveldb.hpp:10,
                 from src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.cpp:2:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::createPoolingDesc(cudnnPoolingStruct**, caffe::PoolingParameter_PoolMethod, cudnnPoolingMode_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:9: error: ‘CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN’ was not declared in this scope
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
         ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: error: there are no arguments to ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ must be available [-fpermissive]
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: At global scope:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: variable or field ‘createActivationDescriptor’ declared void
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                    ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: ‘cudnnActivationDescriptor_t’ was not declared in this scope
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:69: error: ‘activ_desc’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                                                 ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:142:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘mode’
     cudnnActivationMode_t mode) {
                       ^
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:40:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/db.hpp:6,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/db_lmdb.hpp:10,
                 from src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.cpp:2:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::createPoolingDesc(cudnnPoolingStruct**, caffe::PoolingParameter_PoolMethod, cudnnPoolingMode_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:9: error: ‘CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN’ was not declared in this scope
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
         ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: error: there are no arguments to ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ must be available [-fpermissive]
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: At global scope:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: variable or field ‘createActivationDescriptor’ declared void
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                    ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: ‘cudnnActivationDescriptor_t’ was not declared in this scope
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:69: error: ‘activ_desc’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                                                 ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:142:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘mode’
     cudnnActivationMode_t mode) {
                       ^
make: *** [.build_debug/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o] 错误 1
make: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....
make: *** [.build_debug/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o] 错误 1
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:40:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19,
                 from src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp:8:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::createPoolingDesc(cudnnPoolingStruct**, caffe::PoolingParameter_PoolMethod, cudnnPoolingMode_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:9: error: ‘CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN’ was not declared in this scope
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
         ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: error: there are no arguments to ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ must be available [-fpermissive]
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                 ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: At global scope:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: variable or field ‘createActivationDescriptor’ declared void
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                    ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: ‘cudnnActivationDescriptor_t’ was not declared in this scope
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:69: error: ‘activ_desc’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                                                 ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:142:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘mode’
     cudnnActivationMode_t mode) {
                       ^
make: *** [.build_debug/src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.o] 错误 1
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:40:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19,
                 from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,
                 from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:7,
                 from src/caffe/parallel.cpp:12:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::createPoolingDesc(cudnnPoolingStruct**, caffe::PoolingParameter_PoolMethod, cudnnPoolingMode_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:9: error: ‘CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN’ was not declared in this scope
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
         ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: error: there are no arguments to ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor_v4’ must be available [-fpermissive]
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:136:68: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
         CUDNN_PROPAGATE_NAN, h, w, pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                                                ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                        ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: At global scope:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: variable or field ‘createActivationDescriptor’ declared void
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                    ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:40: error: ‘cudnnActivationDescriptor_t’ was not declared in this scope
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:141:69: error: ‘activ_desc’ was not declared in this scope
 inline void createActivationDescriptor(cudnnActivationDescriptor_t* activ_desc,
                                                                 ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:142:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘mode’
     cudnnActivationMode_t mode) {
                       ^
make: *** [.build_debug/src/caffe/parallel.o] 错误 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think I'd better use tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) and [cudnn](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) to your computer. For me, I use cuda 7.5 and cudnn 5.0 that work just fine with the latest Caffe.
2. Extracts cuda and cudnn to some places in your computer, say `</path/to/cuda>` and `</path/to/cudnn>`, respectively
3. In your terminal:

   `sudo cp </path/to/cudnn>/lib64/libcudnn* </path/to/cuda>/lib64`

   `sudo cp </path/to/cudnn>/include/cudnn.h </path/to/cuda>/include`

   `export PATH=</path/to/cuda>/bin:$PATH`

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=</path/to/cuda>/lib64</path/to/cudnn>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

   `source ~/.bashrc`
4. In `Makefile.config`, change this line

   `# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
   CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda`
   to
   `CUDA_DIR := </path/to/cuda>`
5. `make all -j8 && make pycaffe -j8 && make run -j8 && make runtest -j8`

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade cudnn.  If you are on cuda7, grab the latest cudnn that works with cuda7 from nvidia (there will be a link that reads "Download cuDNN v4 (Feb 10, 2016), for CUDA 7.0 and later.").  The install is easy, just untar and copy the include and lib64 contents to your cuda folder. I backed up my cudnn.h and libs just in case but all went smooth.

```
tar -zxf cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-prod.tgz
cd cuda
sudo cp ./lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp ./include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

assuming your cuda folder is /usr/local/cuda/